# Is there a way to link my menu buttons so I can scroll to diffrent parts on the same webpage?

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, scroll

I have a webpage with a set of menubuttons, my question what's the easiest way
to scroll down my page by clicking a button, for example button middle will scroll
to the middle of the webpage, button bottom scrolls down to the bottom simply by using html/css.

In my case I have a button called gallery if I click on it I want my page to move
to the image gallery section on the same page.

Comment: Just use simple anchor links – then the browser jumps to the target when the link is clicked. If you want to make it fancier, you can add some JavaScript on top of that, that actually scrolls the page to that position in a defined timeframe, there’s enough plugins available for that kind of stuff.

Comment: alright I'll try with anchor links, since the website doesn't support anything else besides html and css, thanks I will let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href='#random'>Go</a>
<div id='random'>Hello</div>
```

Now when you click on the 'a' tag it will drop down to the div of id='random'

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following jQuery snippet to animate the scroll action:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

It takes ID as selector.